# How to build dominance frontier for control flow graph?

Tags: graph, compiler-construction, ssa

I would like to understand what a common principle is used for building Ф-functions for nodes.
I read about "**dominance frontier (DF)**" relationship in a graph that allow to build Ф-functions. Here is an example with control-flow graph for simple code snippet:
[control-flow-graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge6ld.png)

Let's consider the definition for DF:

```
DF is a set of nodes w such that x dominates predecessor of w, but x does not strictly dominate w
```

Okay, here is my understanding of this definition. Let's consider: `DF(B1) = { B3, B5, B6, B7 }`
because:

```
dom(B1, B2) & !strictly_dom(B1, B3) & is_predecessor(B2, B3);
dom(B1, B3) & !strictly_dom(B1, B5) & is_predecessor(B3, B5);
dom(B1, B3) & !strictly_dom(B1, B6) & is_predecessor(B3, B6); 
dom(B1, B6) & !strictly_dom(B1, B7) & is_predecessor(B6, B7);
```

Is this right understanding of DF? Could you give me more detailed explanation, please?

Comment: What does "dominate" mean in that context? Do you have a problem understanding the underlying principle or with the implementation in C? I assume the language part is not really relevant for your question.

Comment: @Gerhardh took "C" tag out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to understand the role of dominance frontiers in the context of constructing SSA form is to identify join points in your graph. This is the intuition people use when constructing SSA form on paper.

If a node in your control flow graph has less than 2 predecessors, then it won't be in the dominance frontier of any node - as it cannot be a merge point for competing definitions. The concept of a "dominance frontier" is precisely the nodes where the "dominance" of some node ends (i.e. where its definitions may no longer be the dominant ones; the ones that definitely reach those points, without competition from other alternate paths where other definitions may occur and, thus, reach the same points).

So, just by looking at your control flow graph, we can see that the only nodes with at least 2 predecessors are `B2` and `B7`. So, these nodes will be the ones that form the frontiers of some nodes.

You must appeal to the definition of dominance to know whose frontier is composed of these nodes. By definition, every node dominates itself. So, if we look at the predecessors of the blocks `B2` and `B7`, we can eliminate the ones that don't strictly dominate those nodes.

For `B7`, we have that `B5` and `B6` dominate a predecessor of `B7` (namely, themselves). However, they do not *strictly* dominate `B7` (in fact, they do not dominate `B7` at all). The fact that they both compete for dominance over the definitions that reach `B7`'s is precisely why the dominance frontiers of `B5` and `B6` are both `{B7}`. Intuitively, citing your original graph, you can see that these two predecessors both define `j` and `k`, so when control flow reaches `B7`, whose definitions do you use? You can't tell, since you could go through either to reach `B7`. So, you'd place phi nodes: `j <- ϕ((j, B5), (j, B6))` and `k <- ϕ((k, B5), (k, B6))`. Keeping track of the source of each variable definition you're talking about is important to identify which (re)name you use when you perform renaming (you place phi nodes, then rename).

For `B2`, `B7` is a predecessor and dominates itself by definition. However, it doesn't strictly dominate `B2` as it competes with initial definitions from the entry block, `B1`. Therefore, you'd also place phi nodes to merge those definitions: `j <- ϕ((j, B1), (j, B7))`, `k <- ϕ((k, B1), (k, B7))`. Notice how there's no competing definition for `i` because `i` is never redefined. As far as I can tell, you could constant propagate `i`'s value, `1`, to its usage site and remove the definition.

I recommend reading "A Simple, Fast Dominance Algorithm" by Cooper et al. ([https://www.cs.rice.edu/~keith/EMBED/dom.pdf](https://www.cs.rice.edu/%7Ekeith/EMBED/dom.pdf)), they give a simple algorithm that computes the dominator tree and also an intuitive algorithm (fig 5) for computing the frontiers by walking up the dominator tree.

You're best thinking about dominance frontiers intuitively; which competing definitions can reach a join point? In the suggested `DF(B1)` you give, you have that `B3 ∈ DF(B1)`. This cannot be right. The reason being that the only definitions that can reach `B3` are the ones that leave `B2` (its single predecessor). However, the definitions that enter `B2` are competitive because you could reach `B2` by coming from `B7` or `B1` (hence, as described above, `B2` has to have a leading phi node - the definition created by the phi node is the one that will end up reaching `B3` without competition).

Comment: Wow! Thank you for clear explanation!

Comment: "we have that `B5` and `B6` dominate a predecessor of `B7` (namely, themselves).". This is very important point. I have not paid attention that a node can dominate itself. Also, I got that `not strictly dominates` means that this path is not the only way to get to this node (`B7` can be reached from dominator `B5`, but also from `B6`) and thus we get "ramification". Thank you!